# How to concatenate variable and string in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, string, variables, concatenation

Please don't immediately mark this as a duplicate. I've looked at similar questions but still can't figure this out.

This is what I have currently:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    for(var i=1;i<2;i++)
    {
        $("#MenuBarButton"+i).mouseover(function(){
            $("#ldheMenuBarLayer"+i).stop().animate({height:'66px'},{queue:false, duration:600, easing: 'easeOutBounce'})
        });
        $("#MenuBarButton"+i).mouseout(function(){
            $("#ldheMenuBarLayer"+i).stop().animate({height:'41px'},{queue:false, duration:600, easing: 'easeOutBounce'})
        });
    }
});
```

That doesn't work. Nothing happens and nothing appears in the console. But if I directly replace the `i` with a `1` in each of the `$` function things it works.

I'm not new to programming but I'm new to JavaScript, so am I doing something obviously wrong? Thanks!

**EDIT:** When I say I replace the `i` with a `1`, that's because the IDs are `MenuBarButton1` and `ldheMenuBarLayer1`.

Comment: Your for loop only executes once... Why use a for loop?  if i=1 and it only evaluates to i<2 then it only executes once.  Is that the intent?

Comment: 1. Try forcing the numerical variable `i` to a string: `.. +String(i)`. 2. There is no need for a loop here: `for (var i=1;i<2;i++)` will only "loop" once, with `i=1`.

Comment: @SoylentGreen Because once I get it working with just one button it will be looping through around 5 or 6.

Comment: @Jongware numbers are implicitly made into strings when used in a `+` expression with a string.

Comment: Does this happen with larger loops as well? (more than 1 iterations)

Comment: While I'm not going to answer your question. Why do it like this? Why not assign a class to the item, and use the rel attribute to specify which ldheMenuBarLayer to work against? That way you aren't attaching the events in a loop and potentially blocking the thread.

Comment: @Pointy: I know. But the OP said, "nothing happens" -- best to start with the obvious.

Comment: @Exelian I don't know because I can't test it. I mean, it shows exactly the same results when I increased `i<2` to `i<5`, if that's what you mean.

Comment: @TimEbenezer I have no idea what you mean. I'm not programming the HTML or CSS by hand, it's being generated by a program. All I'm doing is writing a JavaScript. Also I don't know what you mean by blocking the thread.

Comment: @Clonkex Your code should work as is.  A simplified example: http://jsfiddle.net/QQjVj/

Comment: Not really answering your question, but you could use `$('[id^="MenuBarButton"]')` to select all elements with an id attribute starting with "MenuBarButton", so you wouldn't need that loop at all.

Comment: @Clonkex - this has less significance if you can't control the HTML, but if you could, you could assign all MenuBarButtons a class (or you could ask the developer to), which means you only run the .mouseover function once, rather than repeatedly in a loop. While the loop is running the thread for that browser window is blocked. Although it might only be momentary, it can increase significantly if you increased the number of calls made.

Comment: @Jongware Using `String(i)` does nothing. I mean, no change. Using `String(1)` works, so I'm completely confused as to what is different about a constant `1` and a `1` from inside a variable...

Comment: @pawel has made a great suggestion that requires no changing of the HTML

Comment: @TimEbenezer Ok, well I'll come back to that once I figure out what's wrong with my current code. Even if I end up not even using my current code, I want to figure out what's wrong. Also, I am using [Dynamic HTML Editor](http://www.dynamic-html-editor.com/) to create the HTML. I am designing this website alone.

Comment: @pawel Well I already thought of doing a similar thing, but would that not mean that every instance of `ldheMenuBarLayer` would be affected by a mouseover on every instance of `MenuBarButton`? That's why I came up with for-loop.

Comment: @Clonkex  It really sounds like i isn't equal to 1 for you when its run.  Is there some other code that you're running inside the loop that you're not showing?

Comment: @ben336 Nope, that's the entire .js file, and aside from jQuery and jQueryEasing, it's the only file I'm loading.

Comment: @ben336 For whatever reason, your simplified code runs and successfully brings up the alerts. I'm now scanning letter for letter to see if I have something wrong in my code.

Comment: Things to try:  use `console.log()` to verify that the outer selector ("#MenuBarButton" + i) selects one or more elements. Then, in the event handlers, `console.log()` to verify they're being called.

Comment: Is there a way to select multiple #'s using jQuery? That is, HTML ID's. Because they have to be unique, so is there a way of doing `$("#MenuBarButton*")`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic problem you have is that there is only ever one value for `i`. That variable only exists once. The code inside the event handler points to the variable, not to its value when the event handler was created. So take your code that looks like this:

```
$("#ldheMenuBarLayer"+i).stop()...
```

Every time the event handler is run, `i` will be `2`, because we've already gone all the way through the loop.

You need to use the *value* of `i`, not a reference to the variable. You do this by introducing a new scope with an anonymous, immediately-invoked function:

```
for(var i=1;i<=2;i++)
{
    (function(j) {
        $("#MenuBarButton"+j).mouseover(function(){
            $("#ldheMenuBarLayer"+j).stop().animate({height:'66px'},{queue:false, duration:600, easing: 'easeOutBounce'})
        });
        $("#MenuBarButton"+j).mouseout(function(){
            $("#ldheMenuBarLayer"+j).stop().animate({height:'41px'},{queue:false, duration:600, easing: 'easeOutBounce'})
        });
    }(i))
}
```

Leaving aside all of this, it's worth mentioning that this isn't a very jQuery-ish way of going about things. The jQuery way might look like this:

```
var menuBarButtons = $('.menuBarButton').mouseover(function() {
    var idx = menuBarButtons.index(this);

    $('.ldheMenuBarLayer')
        .eq(idx)
        .stop()
        .animate(
             {
                 height: '66px'
             },
             {
                 queue: false,
                 duration: 600,
                 easing: 'easeOutBounce'
             }
         );
});
```

This code won't work (probably). It needs to be based on your markup and page structure. It might ultimately not be possible.

Comment: "You probably want to do the loop for values of i 1 and 2. The code for this is" No, no, I completely understand how loops work and I only need the one loop currently. Once I have the first one working I'll increase it as necessary. Thanks though :)

Comment: Also, I can't change stuff in CSS or HTML so I can't search with a .

Comment: @Clonkex Aha, that makes sense. I have removed that part of my post. You might look into complex selectors like `[id^="MenuBarButton"]`, but this may not be very relevant to you now if you can get the slightly un-jQuery way to work to your satisfaction.

Comment: Is there a way to select multiple #'s using jQuery? That is, HTML ID's. Because they have to be unique, so is there a way of doing `$("#MenuBarButton*")`?

Comment: @Clonkex Yes. You'll find it in my last comment `;-)`. See [the jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/).

Comment: Thanks, but I actually found that page already (amazingly). My problem is I have no idea how to apply the syntax to my code. I don't know HTML well enough to know what an attribute even is. Can I do `$("[id^=MenuBarButton]").etc`?